# Media and graphics website

Tags: graphics

Is there a site like stackoverflow.com for graphics and media related queries ? 
A website covering FinalCut Pro or aftereffects ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that there's such a website with the same structure. I think about the best you might get is fora, such as http://forums.creativecow.net/applefinalcutpro or http://discussions.apple.com/forum.jspa?forumID=939 .